# Texture painting stencil bug 2.8

Tags: texture-painting

I was following a tutorial blender fast track and in the tutorial they were using texture painting with a stencil to put runes on a sword, on the tutorial when using the stencil it shewed up as a see though overlay. on mine nothing appears but I can still use the stencil? It was a lot of trial and error to get an invisible stencil in the right place! is there a known fix for this or did I miss a step? I have been over the tutorial several times with the same result.

Comment: Which version are you using of 2.8 series, and what are your settings for the Texture Alpha option in the Display tab of the tool Properties?

Comment: hi @CraigDJones it is blender v2.81 and the alpha are all set to the default 33%

Comment: Sounds like a graphics driver issue then - do you have a graphics card or a particular chipset for graphics? There may be an issue with the drawing of the stencil.

Comment: I am not sure on the specific graphics driver because its an all in one with integrated graphics AMD Ryzen™ Mobile Processors with Radeon™ Vega Graphics. as I am only starting learning 3D I haven't forked out for a beasty system yet but it is on the to do list :) You may have a point though, I am also running a Linux distribution and they don't always play nice with the hardware.

Comment: Might try a different live distro to see if the graphics might draw better, or maybe check to see if there is a different driver available for your system.

Comment: Humm, it seems like this particular configuration doesn't really have any proper support. all forum questions that are the same have zero responses and I cant see any new available drivers. Might be time to look for that new system.

Comment: Try a live cd image of another distro first to see if it can be solved that way before ditching the system altogether - I had to do that a few years ago and found a version of ubuntu was nicer to me that what I thought would be equal , lubuntu.

Comment: Thankyou @CraigDJones lubuntu is what I am running at the moment but I will have a hunt around and see what I can find.

Comment: Mr. digitalGasim please watch this video might help you
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ktFY3pcU1lo

Answer (score 0):

If you have problems with rune emission (making the whole blade glowing instead of the runes) - just make sure that the left gradient button in rune emission color ramp is black